# Transform values different from a pre-defined range into missing and compute a new varible based on specific columns using str.contains and pandas

Tags: python, pandas, apply

I have a dataset with missing cases (NAs) and "impossible" values, which is defined as any value different from 1,2,3,4, or 5.

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'aut_a_p1_r1': {131: 52.0, 106: 4.0, 80: 4.0, 108: 3.0, 303: 5.0, 145: nan, 172: nan, 103: nan, 67: nan, 59: nan, 7: 2.0, 9: 3.0, 248: 5.0, 219: 3.0, 134: 5.0, 105: 3.0, 176: 3.0, 245: 1.0, 271: 4.0, 249: 4.0}, 'aut_a_p1_r2': {131: 4.0, 106: 5.0, 80: 5.0, 108: 4.0, 303: 5.0, 145: nan, 172: nan, 103: nan, 67: nan, 59: nan, 7: 4.0, 9: 5.0, 248: 4.0, 219: 4.0, 134: 3.0, 105: 4.0, 176: 4.0, 245: 3.0, 271: 5.0, 249: 4.0}, 'aut_a_p1_r3': {131: 5.0, 106: 5.0, 80: 5.0, 108: 4.0, 303: 5.0, 145: nan, 172: nan, 103: nan, 67: nan, 59: nan, 7: 5.0, 9: 5.0, 248: 5.0, 219: 5.0, 134: 5.0, 105: 5.0, 176: 5.0, 245: 4.0, 271: 5.0, 249: 4.0}, 'aut_a_p1_r4': {131: 3.0, 106: 2.0, 80: 2.0, 108: 3.0, 303: 1.0, 145: nan, 172: nan, 103: nan, 67: nan, 59: nan, 7: 4.0, 9: 4.0, 248: 3.0, 219: 3.0, 134: 2.0, 105: 2.0, 176: 3.0, 245: 2.0, 271: 2.0, 249: 2.0}})
```

My goal is to convert all variables to numeric and then create a new column with the summation of other specific variables ignoring the missing cases. If the value of the cell is outside some pre-defined range, convert it to missing. If possible, not sum columns in which missing (Nan) is present instead of return 0 as result.

This is the code I´m trying:

```
#Convert to numeric
df.loc[:,df.columns.str.contains("aut_a_")] = df.loc[:,df.columns.str.contains("aut_a_")].apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')

# Convert values != 1,2,3,4,5 to missing
????

# Sum
df["aut_sum"] = df.loc[:,df.columns.str.contains("aut_a_")].sum(axis=1)
df["aut_sum"]
```

Please, feel free to improve my code.

Comment: Do you want to override your dataframe or just apply conditions?

Comment: Just apply conditions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `mask`:

```
df['aut_sum'] = df.dropna(how='all').filter(like='aut_a_').mask((df < 1) | (df > 5)).sum(axis=1)
print(df)

# Output
     aut_a_p1_r1  aut_a_p1_r2  aut_a_p1_r3  aut_a_p1_r4  aut_sum
131         52.0          4.0          5.0          3.0     12.0
106          4.0          5.0          5.0          2.0     16.0
80           4.0          5.0          5.0          2.0     16.0
108          3.0          4.0          4.0          3.0     14.0
303          5.0          5.0          5.0          1.0     16.0
145          NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN      NaN
172          NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN      NaN
103          NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN      NaN
67           NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN      NaN
59           NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN      NaN
7            2.0          4.0          5.0          4.0     15.0
9            3.0          5.0          5.0          4.0     17.0
248          5.0          4.0          5.0          3.0     17.0
219          3.0          4.0          5.0          3.0     15.0
134          5.0          3.0          5.0          2.0     15.0
105          3.0          4.0          5.0          2.0     14.0
176          3.0          4.0          5.0          3.0     15.0
245          1.0          3.0          4.0          2.0     10.0
271          4.0          5.0          5.0          2.0     16.0
249          4.0          4.0          4.0          2.0     14.0
```

Comment: `df.filter(like='aut_a_').mask((df < 1) | (df > 5), 0).sum(axis=1)`

Comment: The fill value `0` is important?

Comment: no, only avoid floats

Comment: Oh, nice point! but it doesn't work if values are already float?

Comment: Thank you. Any chance to not sum if Nan is present instead of having the 0 in `aut_sum` ?

Comment: @Luis. I updated my answer. Can you check it please?

Answer (score 3):

You want to use `filter` for searching a label in index/columns:

```
target = df.filter(regex='aut_a_*') 
df['aut_sum'] = target.dropna().where(target.isin(np.arange(1, 6)), 0).sum(1)
```

Output:

```
    aut_a_p1_r1  aut_a_p1_r2  aut_a_p1_r3  aut_a_p1_r4  aut_sum
131         52.0          4.0          5.0          3.0     12.0
106          4.0          5.0          5.0          2.0     16.0
80           4.0          5.0          5.0          2.0     16.0
108          3.0          4.0          4.0          3.0     14.0
303          5.0          5.0          5.0          1.0     16.0
145          NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN      NaN
172          NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN      NaN
103          NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN      NaN
67           NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN      NaN
59           NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN      NaN
7            2.0          4.0          5.0          4.0     15.0
9            3.0          5.0          5.0          4.0     17.0
248          5.0          4.0          5.0          3.0     17.0
219          3.0          4.0          5.0          3.0     15.0
134          5.0          3.0          5.0          2.0     15.0
105          3.0          4.0          5.0          2.0     14.0
176          3.0          4.0          5.0          3.0     15.0
245          1.0          3.0          4.0          2.0     10.0
271          4.0          5.0          5.0          2.0     16.0
249          4.0          4.0          4.0          2.0     14.0
```

Comment: Thank you. Any chance to not sum if Nan is present instead of having the 0 in `aut_sum` ?

Comment: You mean dropping the row or having an `NaN`?

Comment: Just add a `dropna` before the mask. I've edited it.

Comment: Having a NaN. Now it´s great! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
df["aut_sum"] = (df.applymap(lambda x: x if x in [1,2,3,4,5] else np.nan)
.filter(like="aut_a_").dropna().sum(axis=1) )
```